# working with a very large JSON object in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I am working with a huge JSON object and i need to extract a single parameter from it.

Is there a way to query the JSON object for the parameter?

Comment: How large is large, in KB/MB/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You need a *streaming* JSON parser for that, i.e. a parser that produces events to which you listen as it goes through the JSON input, as opposed to document-based parsers, such as `NSJSONSerialization` of iOS 5+.

One of such parsers is [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/yajl-2.0.1/): although it is a C library, you can use it from Objective C as well: all you need to do is defining a [`yajl_callbacks`](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/yajl-2.0.1/structyajl__callbacks.html), put pointers to the handlers for the type of the item that you wish to extract, call the parser, and let the parser do the rest.